# How to disable Software's that doesn't have admin Privilege's on windows like Process Explorer

Tags: windows, network-administration

I need help on how to Disable software that doesn't have Admin privilege. Like Process Explorer. software/applications that just straight up install to the user without a Admin password. I Don't want my employees to see what's on my Task Manager for security purposes. Also, this might help me on 3rd party software that can bypass my Admin settings too. I tried checking Gpedit but it seems I'm not getting enough info. Currently, I'm using windows 10. Please help

Comment: Your employees are not allowed to see what processes are running? I'm curious how that is going to play out because there are several ways to get to that information. On top of my head, `cmd -> tasklist`, `pwsh -> get-process`, `standard task manager` .

Comment: Hi Lieven, Yes your right employees are not allowed to see what's running. Only the administrator will have access to it. If it needs to disable cmd then It will be disabled as well.

Comment: You could take a look at applocker or the [wrapper](https://github.com/microsoft/AaronLocker) from Aaron Margosis around it. I never used either so no idea how far it’ll take you

Comment: Note that as long as I’m able to drop a file somewhere, it will be difficult, if not impossible to stop me from simply using the windows api to get a list of processes.

Comment: Thank you for the info, i will try the applocker and see if it can help out. I haven't tried the wrapper but I will check it as well. Thanks!

Comment: What security purpose does it serve to prevent employees from enumerating running processes? If they aren't administrators they can't do anything about processes they don't own. (By the way, it's completely pointless to disable cmd.exe, because cmd.exe is a program, not a security boundary.)